# Should close votes be cast on unsuitable questions that have been answered?

Tags: discussion, flagging, voting-to-close

If there is a question that is not suitable for the site as per the FAQ, but has  been answered (correctly), is it still suitable to cast a close vote?

For example, [this](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/34643/about-corolla-theme-logo) question is not a good fit for the site, and should instead have been in the theme's issue queue (as noted in the answer).  However, it has been answered and the answer is correct - should a close vote/flag still be cast?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question you are referring is acceptable because it is not showing an error message caused by a bug in code, such as in the case of a PHP warning, or error message.
I would not consider it too localized, as the answer is still valid until the 3.x branch is not more stable, and it could interest any user who uses that branch.

Differently, if the question were not a good fit the site, it would not be a good fit whenever it has an accepted answer, an answer, or no answers at all.

Comment: So basically, regardless of whether or not the answer is right, wrong, accepted, or whatever - if the question is a poor fit then flagging or voting to close is acceptable?

Comment: That is correct. An answer can save a question, but it needs to be a very good answer that, for example, considers any possible situation, in the case of too broad questions.